# NativeScript Support for Custom SDK's and Bluetooth LTE

Tags: nativescript, hybrid-mobile-app

Does NativeScript support using your own custom iOS and Android SDK's that allow you to connect and communicate with external devices via Bluetooth LTE? We have native iOS and Android SDK that can communicate with our own Bluetooth LTE devices but curious if this low level control available with a framework such as NativeScript?

Currently develop native apps in iOS and Android that work but would like to determine if hybrid mobile frameworks, such as NativeScript, are suitable for this level of control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, NativeScript is particularly friendly when consuming native APIs. This includes using 3rd party native SDKs for iOS and Android. More information can be found [in the documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/accessing-native-apis-with-javascript).

You don't need to create wrappers or bridges. All native APIs which are imported in the application are directly available for consuming without additional overhead.